# Error 800a01a8: WScript Object Required

Tags: vbscript, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, wsh

I'm trying to use the current path of the script using the following snippet:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
```

But, it keeps throwing up the error saying

> 'Wscript' Object Required.

Comment: Your code produces no errors for me!

Comment: Is there something you've done to change whether 64bit or 32bit wscript.exe is running on your machine?

Comment: @GTAVLover I'm running this on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine, is there anything I need to do to fix up which wscript.exe should be used (System32/SysWOW64)?

Comment: Do not create that object wscript.shell.... It works on some of the machines without setting that object if the code is stored in a .vbs file. Just comment that line and try again.

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Tried, shows the same error!

Comment: Where does it throw the error, on line... Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  or when you try to use PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)

Comment: Also, does this work?.....PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(oShell.ScriptFullName)

Comment: @Harshil same....I also ran your script on my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit machine.no errors!.Can you show which line shows errors?

Comment: @GTAVLover Here's how the error goes:
Description: Object required: 'Wscript'
Line(21):" PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) "

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar It throws error on PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) line.

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Your change doesn't work either. It gives the following error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'oShell.ScriptFullName'

Comment: Are you running the code as a plain VBScript file (.vbs) with either `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`? Or are you using some other engine (HTA, QTP, ...)? Not all VBScript engines have a builtin `WScript` object.

Comment: I ran this with CScript and it also output my current directory......

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No, I'm running it as a plain VBScript with wscript.exe. I'm somehow feeling that there's an issue due to the 32 bit/64bit wscript.exe being picked up for execution.

Comment: The code snippet you posted should work just fine with the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of both `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` and should put the path of the folder containing the script in the variable `PathName`. The code should not produce any output or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, use the following code to get current path of the script:

```
Dim oFileSystemObj: Set oFileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

PathName = oFileSystemObj.GetParentFolderName(oFileSystemObj.GetAbsolutePathName("."))
```

Comment: For me, it is giving a higher level directory, not returning the exact sub-directory that I'm operating the script from.

Comment: @Harshil okay. Updated the answer. ;-)